# Mysql: Is it practical to create a separate table for each user's posts

Tags: database, database-design, e-commerce

So I have a website where users create their own 'shops' and then they can put items in the shops, so would it be practical to create a table for each user's shops or should I just add user IDs to posts?

Comment: no, it's not practical and good design to do so. [Relational Database Design](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add user ids to shops/posts.  There are numerous reasons why you do not want to have separate tables for each user:

- MySQL is designed to handle tables with lots of rows, not lots of tables with the same structure.
- Structuring queries that goes across tables will require combining lots of different tables.
- A small change to the data structure, such as adding a new column, becomes a nightmare.
- Foreign key references to the shops becomes impossible.
- If the data for a user doesn't fill a single data page, you end up wasting *a lot* of memory.

There are some reasons why splitting data into separate tables might be necessary.  Here are some possible reasons:

- Access is more easily managed at the table level than at the row level.
- Replication of the data for each user might have different requirements.
- An external entity requires that the data be in separate tables or databases.

However, the first set of reasons seems to weigh much more heavily to single table/entity structures.  These more advanced concerns do not appear to be an issue.